# Retractions of ENR

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $i:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ be an imbedding of a topological space $X$. Assume that there exists an open neighborhood $U$ containing $i(X)$ which also admits a retraction $p:U\rightarrow X$. The question is whether any two such retractions $p_1$ and $p_2$ are homotopic? (It is allowed to shrink $U$ is needed.)

Comment: Formally speaking, this question is not right--one range is $\ X=p_2(U)\ (?)\ $, and the other is $\ p(X)=p_2(X)=i(X)\ (?).\ $ Formally or not, but I am not sure what your question is. Also, you have $\ p\ p_1\ p_2\ $ which confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider $H: U \times [0; 1] \to \mathbb{R}^N$, $H_t=tp_1+(1-t)p_2$. Clearly, $H^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of $\iota(X) \times [0, 1]$, by compactness of $[0; 1]$ it contains an open set of of the form $\tilde{U} \times [0, 1]$ with $\tilde{U}$ open neighbourhood of $\iota(X)$, so for example $p_1 \circ H |_{\tilde{U}}$ is a homotopy between the two retracts on $\tilde{U}$.